# OneDrive session is lost when refresh of the page is made

Tags: session, onedrive

After loggin in OneDrive through a web application as explained here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659751.aspx), I can see that a session (WL.getSession()) is obtained correctly. However, if I make a refresh on the page, it is getting lost. I guess this is due to some cookies management. Is it possible to have the session not cleared at refresh?

Thanks,
Stanislav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, you should call `WL.login` or otherwise check login status first (see [WL.getloginStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550842.aspx)). These will return a session object if the user is logged in and has consented, so on refresh your session object should not be null unless they have logged out and you need to sign them in again. You may be "losing" the session depending on when you are calling `WL.getSession()`

Check out the [interactive SDK sample on signing users in](http://isdk.dev.live.com/dev/isdk/ISDK.aspx?category=scenarioGroup_core_concepts&index=0)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the samples - they are quite useful. However, if I try to make a WL.login (or any call to WL), I get a message saying that I need WL.init first. When I put the init and then login, there is no problem. This seems very strange behaviour to me as why WL object kind of becomes removed at F5 button.

Comment: Yes. WL.init is always required so that the app can be validated with it's Client Id, and a redirect url for handling login